# How to go from a list to sorted tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here's the task:
I have ten cards in a list with these values: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
Im supposed to gather three cards with the total value of 21. I have to print every possible combinations of three cards with the total value of 21 as sorted tuples. Example of the output:
(2, 8, 11)
(2, 9, 10)
(3, 7, 11)
(3, 8, 10)
(4, 6, 11)
...
I have NO idea how to do this and where to start.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 1):

itertools.combinations will give all possible combinations. Mathematically, nCr = n!/((n-r)! *r!).

```
# If n = 4 and r =3 then
# nCr = 4!/1!*3!  = 4*3*2*1 / (3*2*1)*(1) = 4.  

More help on itertools - 
Init signature: itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
Docstring:     
Return successive r-length combinations of elements in the iterable.

combinations(range(4), 3) --> (0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,3), (1,2,3)
Type:           type
Subclasses:
```

So, by itertools.combination we can get all the possible combinations of length 3.

```
import itertools
cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
all_combinations = itertools.combinations(cards, 3)
```

Now, to filter only those combination which has sum =21 we can use list comprehension. Python has an in-built function sum(iterable) to do this task.

```
Signature: sum(iterable, /, start=0)
Docstring:
Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
reject non-numeric types.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

The last requirement was to sort the tuple which can be done via another in-built function sorted.

```
result = [
    tuple(sorted(combination))
    for combination in all_combinations
    if sum(combination) == 21
]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations` to generate all possible 3-card combinations, and sort each in ascending order

```
import itertools
cards = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

for combo in itertools.combinations(cards, 3):
    print(tuple(sorted(combo)))

# alternatively, if you need to collect them in a list for later processing...

output = [ tuple(sorted(combo)) for combo in itertools.combinations(cards, 3) ]
```